# RewriteRule multiple folders deep

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have the url `localhost/parent/admin/news/edit/2` and I want to rewrite it to run `localhost/parent/admin/news/edit.php?id=2`. A majority of the RewriteRule examples I have looked at (such as [this one](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)) used the following to catch a rewrite just after the domain:

```
RewriteRule    ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    show_a_product.php?product_id=$1    [NC,L]
```

However, as far as I can tell `^` denotes the start of the string and, since my forward is well beyond the start it won't work. Thus I have come up with the following:

```
RewriteRule    edit/([0-9]+)$    edit.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Logically, I feel it should work and I used [the RegExr test](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?30evn) to try it out and that service agrees. When I add an `R` flag to forward, however, it seems the rule is pointing the page to `localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/parent/edit.php?id=2`, from which I can surmise two problems:

1. It is forwarding to the file on my computer instead of the localhost server (triggering an Access Forbidden!)
2. It is cutting out the `news/` section all together.

Hopefully someone can help me solve this issue as I've spent a couple hours fooling around with different combinations to no avail.

*Edit: I should add that the reason I want to catch edit/# is because there will be multiple sections with an edit/# and I'd like to catch them all with one rule as opposed to writing multiple specific rules for each section.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's what should work:

```
RewriteRule /parent/admin/news/edit/([0-9]+)$ /parent/admin/news/edit.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L].
```